# Spotify: Create Playlist

Tags: node.js, spotify

Extending https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples - the code in the authorization_code folder.

It logs out access_token okay, but then hangs at the post request:

```
app.get('/createPlaylist', function(req, res) {

  console.log('access_token=' + access_token)

  request.post(
      'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/playlists',
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: {
          "collaborative": false,
          "description": null,
//        "external_urls": {
//          "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/thelinmichael/playlist/7d2D2S200NyUE5KYs80PwO"
//        },
//    "followers": {
//      "href": null,
//          "total": 0
//    },
//        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/thelinmichael/playlists/7d2D2S200NyUE5KYs80PwO",
//        "id": "7d2D2S200NyUE5KYs80PwO",
          "href": null,
          "id": null,
          "images": [],
          "name": "A Generated Playlist",
          "owner": {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/1150816110"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/1150816110",
            "id": "1150816110",
            "type": "user",
            "uri": "spotify:user:1150816110"
          },
          "public": true,
//          "snapshot_id": "s0o3TSuYnRLl2jch+oA4OEbKwq/fNxhGBkSPnvhZdmWjNV0q3uCAWuGIhEx8SHIx",
          "tracks": {
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/thelinmichael/playlists/7d2D2S200NyUE5KYs80PwO/tracks",
//            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/kb8mc65qdvz4lz0gdk0i4ztp3/playlist/46RFjEgbskxglR8rVsu38x/tracks",
            "items": [],
            "limit": 100,
            "next": null,
            "offset": 0,
            "previous": null,
            "total": 0
          },
          "type": "playlist",
//          "uri": "spotify:user:thelinmichael:playlist:7d2D2S200NyUE5KYs80PwO"
        }
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
        }
      }
  );
});
```

Any idea what is wrong?

'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

What details StackOverflow? I just wanna know why the POST request hangs.

Modified my code to Kevin's specs ... can't believe I misread output for input ... but it still hangs ... node version v12.14.1

```
app.get('/createPlaylist', function (req, res) {

  console.log('access_token=' + access_token)

  request.post(
      'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/playlists',
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: {
          name: 'A generated playlist',
          public: true,
          collaborative: false,
          description: 'Generated at ' + Date.now(),
        }
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log(body);
        }
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: Access token format as written in console log:

`´´
access_token=BQCJOc78SQAjd2dRcXOrORO4wkCBgj-tn9xqajaJbQoPdQ7JbMQ9faFcVXRO9a_swEDMcc4Aa1brNwTt7xbibXu5YHnD7jOjdvsZciAyiY3xis5y9GAq0ajGUOYrn2Bkjz5eNaTEzBQ7t09R93unf3b3EOkYQg
```

Comment: Well ... at least Spotify's manual playlist creation isn't broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your code [to the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/), it looks like the code is sending the JSON output as the input in the example.

To create a playlist, [there are only 4 body parameters](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/):

1. `name` - string - required
2. `public` - boolean - optional
3. `collaborative` - boolean - optional
4. `description` - string - optional.

I don't know where all the other information is coming from but the API could be hanging up on all of it.
Also be sure you have [the right scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#list-of-scopes) involved with permission to create a playlist for a user.

The request would look trimmed down:

```
request.post(
      'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/playlists',
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: {
           name: 'A generated playlist',
           public: true,
           description: 'A playlist generated by JS'
        }
      }
...
```

Comment: Oh dear ... was that the output? I thought it was the input ... It was a little odd with all those IDs, but I thought the example was editing a playlist